# Navigation (Dropdown) in Crafter

Tags: crafter-cms

Pretty new to Crafter CMS and so far its all good. I created a HTML/CSS3 Blueprint from the empty one in studio and need some assistance. I have managed to get everything working (Blog posts and all) but I cant seem to wrap my head around dropdown menus in the navigation. I have a parent page (no content) that needs to have about 4 child pages under it (dropdown). Can anyone please point me in the corect direction where I can make thois happen.

Have been all over the web, but as you might know, Crafter does not have as much of a community as one would hope. Your assistance is highly appreciated.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You didn't specify the framework you're using. Crafter CMS supports building applications as:

- FreeMarker as HTML applications
- Pure headless, example: React, Vue, Angular, Native Mobile

Assuming your navigation is based on your Information Architecture (folder structure), then:

- If you're using FreeMarker, you can build the nav with this: https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.1/developers/projects/engine/api/templating-api.html#rendering-navigation
- If you're using pure-headless, you can build the nav with this: https://docs.craftercms.org/en/3.1/developers/projects/engine/api/site/navigation/tree.html

With Crafter CMS, you can also do navigation based on:

- Search
- A single XML files that holds the navigation
- Something else...

Regarding your comment on the community, you should join us on Slack. Visit https://craftercms.org for a link.

Comment: Hi Sumerz, thanks for your assistance and response. I am using freemarker. Will deffinetly joing the family on slack. Much appreciated.